# Is this shuffling algorithm sufficiently random for an iOS card game?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, categories

Didn't wanna just post, "Hey, guys, can you come up with an awesome randomization method for me?" so I've been studying algorithms for shuffling a deck of cards, creating truly random permutations, etc., ALL DAY LONG and it's been rrrrrrrreally daunting.  Finally settled on a simpler approach, shown below.  While I do want to create a quality game, of course, I'm not going to be using this algorithm in an online casino or anything.  It's just an iOS game.  So, is this random/memory-efficient enough?  Or should I be giving this even MORE time and effort?  TIA

Aside:  Whenever I write "TIA," I think, "This is Africa," not "Thanks in advance."

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (Shuffle)

-(void)shuffle
    {
        for (int i = [self count] - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:(arc4random() % ([self count] - 1))
                      withObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }

    @end
```

EDIT:

Ok.  Wanted to run some test code so I don't post something dumb.  :)  In response to Adam and Nielsbot, you're recommending something more like this?

```
-(void)shuffle
{
    for (int i = [self count] - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:(arc4random_uniform([self count] - 1))
                  withObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Is that right?

Would there be any benefit to repeating it, like so?

```
-(void)shuffle
{
for (int i = [self count] - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:(arc4random_uniform([self count] - 1))
              withObjectAtIndex:i];
}

for (int i = [self count] - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:(arc4random_uniform([self count] - 1))
                  withObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Its better to use arc4random_uniform() instead of arc4random()

Comment: @adam I just came here to say that. From the man page: "`arc4random_uniform()` will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound. `arc4random_uniform()` is recommended over constructions like `arc4random() % upper_bound` as it avoids 'modulo bias' when the upper bound is not a power of two."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's almost the so called [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), it's O(n) as time complexity and memory efficience is not considerable since you don't allocate anything.

The only thing I'd change is the randomly chosen index that would be in range `[0, i]` for i-th iteration instead that the whole range (to avoid just swapping two elements twice), then it would become the algorithm I linked.

Comment: This is what I came here to post. The Fisher-Yates Shuffle is efficient and unbiased. If you don't bound it to `[0, i)` (note, not `[0, i]` as Jack suggested) then you get a biased shuffle. And no, there's no reason to shuffle it multiple times.

Comment: Actually if you restrict the range and exclude the ith element you get a biased version, since an element can't stay in its initial position, you end up obtaining the Sattolo's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Sattolo.27s_algorithm

Comment: Oops, you're totally right. Somehow I flipped the meaning of `]` and `)` without realizing it (which is doubly funny as I didn't question `[`).